# dynamically updating two arrays with select

Tags: angular, typescript, forms

I have 2 arrays, the personnel array which has all the personnel assigned to a project (empty initially) and an availableUsers array which has a list of all users in the system. (each user is an object).

this is my ngOnInit

```
 ngOnInit(): void {
    this.personnel = [];
    this.availableUsers = this.usersService.getAllUsers();
    this.addPersonnelForm = new FormGroup({
      'addSelect': new FormControl(null, Validators.required)
    })
```

I have 2 forms in my component, both are simple with only one <select> option and a button,
addPersonnelForm is used to push selected user object to this.personnel and removePersonnelForm is used to push selected user object to this.availableUsers.

this means the object that was selected from the respective array in either of these forms must be removed from that array(because a user can only be in avaliableUsers or personnel, not both)

my html + form code:

```
<table class="table">
      <thead class="table-dark">
      <tr>
        <th scope="col">#</th>
        <th scope="col">Name</th>
        <th scope="col">Email</th>
        <th scope="col">role</th>
      </tr>
      <tr class="table-light" *ngFor="let person of personnel; let i = index">
        <td>{{i+1}}</td>
        <td>{{person.name}}</td>
        <td>{{person.email}}</td>
        <td>{{person.role}}</td>
      </tr>
      </thead>
    </table>


 <form [formGroup]="addPersonnelForm" (ngSubmit)="addPersonnel()">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="col-md-6" style="float:left;">
          <label class="form-label" for="addSelect">select</label>
          <select id="addSelect" class="form-select" formControlName="addSelect">
            <option *ngFor="let name of availableUsers;" [ngValue]="name">{{name.email}}</option>
          </select>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6" style="float: right">
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-dark" style="float: right; margin-top: 29px">Add</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
```

and my addPersonnel() function:

```
addPersonnel(){
    let selectedUser = this.addPersonnelForm.value.addSelect;
    this.personnel.push(selectedUser);
    let index = this.availableUsers.indexOf(selectedUser)
      this.availableUsers.splice(index, 1);
  }
```

the problem i am facing is that after i select from my addPersonnelForm and submit, it works but the form is NOT cleared on submit, the frontend displays the first object in the availableUsers array such that it is 'selected' while selectedUser STAYS the same as the previously selected value UNLESS i manually select another option and re-select the already 'selected' option, if i hit submit anyway i get errors like ERROR TypeError: person_r4 is null in my HTML table code. I tried using personnelForm.reset() in my addPersonnel() function but nothing happens.

the problem is not in the arrays, they do dynamically change correctly for every user i add/remove(as long as i select my own option after submitting once), the problem is that the form is not cleared on submit and when only 1 user is left in the array, the wrong value is sent to the backend because i can't do what i said earlier.

please help me fix this or provide an alternate solution, thank you.

Comment: Not completely clear what your issue is, but: 1. you can bind `<option>` to the whole `user` object instead of email, like this: `[ngValue]="name"`; 2. you probably need to treat your `personnel` and `availableUser` arrays as immutable in order to fire Angular change detection. That means, create a new array every time you add/remove items.

Comment: i have updated the question does it make more sense now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found the solution, posting it in case it helps anyone,

I simply added a default option that was disabled and pre-selected, and called a setDefaults() method which would get the formControl and patchValue to null.

```
setDefaults() {
    this.addPersonnelForm.get("addSelect").patchValue(null);
    this.removePersonnelForm.get("removeSelect").patchValue(null);
  }

  addPersonnel(){
    let selectedUser = this.addPersonnelForm.value.addSelect;
    this.personnel.push(selectedUser);
    let index = this.availableUsers.indexOf(selectedUser)
    this.availableUsers.splice(index, 1);
    this.setDefaults();
  }

  removePersonnel(){
    this.availableUsers.push(this.removePersonnelForm.value.removeSelect)
    let index = this.personnel.indexOf(this.removePersonnelForm.value.removeSelect)
    this.personnel.splice(index, 1);
    this.setDefaults();
  }
```

html:

```
<form [formGroup]="addPersonnelForm" (ngSubmit)="addPersonnel()">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="col-md-6" style="float:left;">
          <label class="form-label" for="addSelect">select</label>
          <select id="addSelect" class="form-select" formControlName="addSelect">
            <option [ngValue]="null" disabled>Select user!</option>
            <option *ngFor="let name of availableUsers;" [ngValue]="name">{{name.email}}</option>
          </select>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6" style="float: right">
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-dark" style="float: right; margin-top: 29px" [disabled]="addPersonnelForm.invalid">Add</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
    <h3 style="margin-top: 100px">Remove Personnel</h3>
    <form [formGroup]="removePersonnelForm" (ngSubmit)="removePersonnel()">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="col-md-6" style="float:left;">
          <label class="form-label" for="removeSelect">select</label>
          <select id="removeSelect" class="form-select" formControlName="removeSelect">
            <option [ngValue]="null" disabled>Select user!</option>
            <option *ngFor="let person of personnel" [ngValue]="person">{{person.email}}</option>
          </select>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6" style="float: right">
          <button class="btn btn-dark" style="float: right; margin-top: 29px" [disabled]="removePersonnelForm.invalid">Remove</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I correctly understand your issue, you want to clear `formValue` on every form submit. Calling `reset()` in your `addPersonnel()` function is the right way to do that and it seems to me that it works as expected: [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-my5hab?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts).

Optionally you can pass a value to `reset()` like this:

```
this.addPersonnelForm.reset({addSelect: null});
```